# Calculating percentage over subselect SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that records events regarding email campaigns. I want to figure out the percentage of campaigns where there was more than one event happening for the campaign.

First I calculated the number of events happening in each campaign:

```sql
select count(*) as counter
               from campaigns_log
               where event IN ('send', 'open')
                 and campaign_id is not null
               group by campaign_id, email
```

Then I grouped the campaigns in the condition whether more than one event happened:

```sql
select count(counter) as occurences, IF(counter > 1, 2, 1) as grouper
         from (select count(*) as counter
               from campaigns_log
               where event IN ('send', 'open')
                 and campaign_id is not null
               group by campaign_id, email) as counters_table
         group by grouper
```

Sample result:

```
occurences ¦ grouper
132        ¦ 1
360        ¦ 2
```

Now I want to calculate for each row the percentage of total occurrences. So something like this:

```
occurences ¦ grouper ¦ percentage
132        ¦ 1       ¦ 132/(132+360)
360        ¦ 2       ¦ 360/(132+360)
```

I tried this, but it does not work, it does not properly calculate the sum total:

```sql
select *, occurences/(select sum(occurences))
from (
         select count(counter) as occurences, IF(counter > 1, 2, 1) as grouper
         from (select count(*) as counter
               from campaigns_log
               where event IN ('send', 'open')
                 and campaign_id is not null
               group by campaign_id, email) as counters_table
         group by grouper
     ) as occurences_table group by occurences, grouper
```

Any idea where is my mistake in the last step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use subquery for total count and divide

```
select a.occurences,a.grouper, (a.occurences/c.total) as percentage
from (select count(counter) as occurences, IF(counter > 1, 2, 1) as grouper
             from (select count(*) as counter
                   from campaigns_log
                   where event IN ('send', 'open')
                     and campaign_id is not null
                   group by campaign_id, email) as counters_table
             group by grouper
   ) a,
    (select sum(occurences) total from
    (select count(counter) as occurences, IF(counter > 1, 2, 1) as grouper
             from (select count(*) as counter
                   from campaigns_log
                   where event IN ('send', 'open')
                     and campaign_id is not null
                   group by campaign_id, email) as counters_table
             group by grouper
   ) b )c
```

Comment: I just run the SQL against the data. I got `0.1051` and `0.2866` respectively. This does not add up to `1`. So there is something missing.

Comment: Yes? I do not understand the comment. I am looking for the percentage of occurrences of the total for each row.

Comment: if you divide 132 by 492 then what will be answer? have you checked it? it wanted result in percentage column 132/492 which equal to 0.2683

Comment: Yes, but I get `0.1051` and `0.2866` respectively for the first and second row. Instead of `0.2682` and `0.7317` respectively that I should get.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202068/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-patrick-kusebauch).